# How to add landing page in Netsuite (SCA) without CMS

Tags: content-management-system, netsuite, suitecommerce

How to create new landing page on SCA (Netsuite) Vinson version without CMS/SMT. i am trying to do so because my CMS is not working. Please give me the steps to create it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CMS is the preferred method for creating static or landing pages in Netsuite SCA.
Please make sure you exhaust all option before trying alternatives.
Maybe it is due to some simple mistake such as you selected different CMS/SMT Adapter version in SCA Setup or Configuration.

Alternative methods are creating Custom Module.
If there are products to be displayed, you can use Commerce Categories

Answer (score 0):

you have to create your own module for this. Its so easy, let me know if need more details.